# Only using some data from shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

How can I use only a few of the areas outlined in a shapefile? In this case, my shapefile has all of the ZIP codes for a U.S. state, and I would only like to display the ZIP codes for a particular city. Is there any way to do this?

Also, some of the ZIP codes are partially in the city, and partially out of it. How would I go about editing the boundaries of the outlined areas?

Answer (score 0):

Select the rows you want to display in the attribute table and save as a new shapefile, make sure the 'save only selected features' box ticked. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJzq92IcpYg)